# Large Cardinal Consequences of $\kappa$-Suslin Hypothesis

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, large-cardinals

$\kappa$-Suslin Hypothesis ($\kappa$-SH) for the infinite regular cardinal $\kappa$ says that every tree of height $\kappa$ either has a branch of length $\kappa$ or an antichain of cardinality $\kappa$ (i.e. there is no $\kappa$-Suslin tree).

**Example:** It is known that GCH+$\omega_2$-SH implies that $\omega_2$ is Mahlo in $L$.

**Question:** What are other known large cardinal consequences of $\kappa$-SH for different regular cardinals $\kappa$?

Comment: Most of these proofs work out just as they do in other regular cardinals. You start with a Mahlo cardinal in $L$, you Levy-collapse it into some other cardinal, and the result follows (as it does in the case of $\omega_2$). The real issue begins when you want it to happen to successor of singular cardinals, and when you want two successive cardinals to have this property. I don't know enough about either cases to write an answer, though.